# Хочется поставить тире

Tags: орфография

В общем, ситуация немного странная. Есть рассказ (фэнтези, сетература). Речь идет о Богине, имя которой - Море. Т.е. Море - это одновременно и море, и имя богини, т.е. герои обожествляют море, не отделяют его от своего божества. Т.е. если Посейдон - это был персонаж, а управлял он морями - т.е. было раздельно. То тут сама вода как бы содержит в себе неотъемлемую божественную сущность.

И вот в тексте встречается предложение "Храм Богини-Моря открылся передо мной..." Корректно ли в данном случае постановка тире или это просто моя дурацкая привычка (мне все время хочется поставить тире между словами в словосочетании, которые, по моему мнению, не должны быть отделены друг от друга). Но если бы не было тире, то можно было бы прочитать как "Бог моря Посейдон". А тут смысл в обратном: Море - это имя богини, а не обозначение того, чем она управляет.

Заранее за такое длинное и запутанное объяснение. Надеюсь, кто-нибудь мне подскажет, что тут и как, что можно, а что нельзя

Answer (score 4):

По идее, здесь имя богини склоняться не должно, поэтому фраза при использовании слова *море* как имени для богини звучала бы так - *"Храм Богини Море открылся передо мной..."* (ср имена *Шагане, Гаяне*).

Comment: А почему Богиня с большой буквы? Для ясности можно было бы сказать"Храм богини  с удивительным и властным именем Море открылся передо мной..."

Comment: @Людмила, у автора с большой буквы написано, а в использование заглавных букв у слов, связанных с религией, я стараюсь не лезть. К тому же тут "Богиня" может быть частью наименования храма.

Comment: @Марк Из, при всем уважении, сложно положиться на мнение человека, который в своем ответе совершил столько орфографических ошибок (предположу, что, может, писали с мобильного, поэтому Т9 помешал, но все же)
склонятЬся 
словА 
именИ

Comment: @Маленькая М, спасибо за указанные ошибки, исправил. А доверять мне я и не прошу, поэтому и привёл рассуждения: почему считаю так, а не иначе.